# Download uploaded meteor app

Tags: meteor

I've just deployed a meteor app, and all is working good, but the problem is that i had to format my computer, and I lost all the files.
Now i want to download the app but i see that all the files are not the same on the server.

I did a mup deploy to the server but now the files on the server are not the same i had on my computer. I know this sound as a stupid question but, after the code is deployed.

I've obviously tried to go in the server to the /opt/{appname} folder. but the files there are not the same i had on my computer.

Is there a way to download the app??

Comment: I'm afraid not, when using mup, then bundling process happens on your local machine and only the bundled app is sent to the server. You could still retrieve the bundled files and start from there instead of from scratch...

Comment: Worse, the bundled files will all be minified. The comments will all have been stripped out and the variables all renamed, to a,b,c etc...

Comment: This is a good lesson in using a distributed revision control and source code management service like GitHub